# What are practical examples of Toeplitz matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, big-list, applications, toeplitz-matrices

A [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) is one in which each descending diagonal from left to right is constant. Given that structure, matrix operations are sometimes much faster. Where are Toeplitz matrices likely to occur?

Comment: Some applications are boundary value problems, convolutions, and simulations of "small-world" networks.

Comment: I was hoping for a specific example. A "small-world" network of what exactly?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network) for a discussion of small-world networks.  A way to construct the adjacency matrices of such graphs is to start with a Toeplitz matrix, which guarantee connectivity, and add random "shortcut" edges that reduce distances.

Comment: Here's one example: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2020-2747

Answer (score 3):

One application is linear difference equations with constant coefficients. For example, suppose that we have the (minimalistic) [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) (MA) filter $y_k = \frac12 (x_k + x_{k-1})$ with $x_{-1} = 0$. In matrix form,

$$ \begin{bmatrix} y_0 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} = \frac12 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & & \\ 1 & 1 & \\ & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

where the matrix is

- lower triangular because of causality
- bidiagonal because this MA filter is of length $2$
- [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) because the difference equation has constant coefficients.